# What time format is this and how can I reformat it using JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, time-format

What time format is this and how can I reformat it using JQuery?  It's from a pubdate from an podcast XML.

Mon, 26 Jul 2010 19:15:58 -0700

Is there a precise name for this date format?  I haven't seen this exact one anywhere and it's baffling me a bit.  I've tried the plugin listed below but it doesn't work correctly or take this date input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JS understands that format (RFC 1123) :

```
javascript:alert(new Date(Date.parse('Mon, 26 Jul 2010 19:15:58 -0700')))
```

More here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse

Comment: Hot dang, you were right!  Thank you!  Here's what I had to do in order to get it in the format I wanted.  1) Parse the date like MPLUNGJAN said  2) Then slap it through that formatter like so.

var cleanDate = (new Date(Date.parse(item.pubDate)));
      $('#storyDate').empty().append($.format.date(cleanDate, "MM/dd/yyyy"));

Comment: glad to help. JS still has a few built-in surprises like that :-)

Answer (score 0):

You'll need a plugin. A quick search pulled up http://plugins.jquery.com/project/jquery-dateFormat

Comment: Thanks.  Yeah I tried that one, but it doesn't format it correctly.
That plugin only takes these input types:
input dates formats
#1 2009-12-18 10:54:50.546
#2 Wed Jan 13 10:43:41 CET 2010

That's why I wanted to know the specific date format type, so I can be more specific.  Unless you see that I'm doing something wrong.
http://plugins.jquery.com/project/jquery-dateFormat

Comment: Using that plugin, my date begins as this:
<pubDate>Mon, 09 Aug 2010 19:00:36 -0700</pubDate>

I put it through that formatter and it comes out like this:
09/Aug/-0700